# DLIB Python Installation telling me to install Visual Studio for C++ but I already have

Tags: python, visual-studio, dlib

I am trying to install dlib for python 3.9. I've already installed Visual Studio, including the C++ requirements when I installed Visual Studio. I am sure that I installed the correct C++ requirements, and yet I still get this error.

I have restarted my computer several times and yet it does not work.

Error:

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


  You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
  are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
  that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
  development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```